# .NET Entire line match

Tags: .net, regex

I need to check if entire given input matches given pattern.
But wrapping a pattern in `^`/`$` feels like a hack.
Is there a shortcut for:

```
var match = Regex.Match(myInput, "^" + myPattern + "$");
```

?

Comment: Every time you use a regular expression, it feels like a hack.  Your feelings are normal. :)

Comment: Remember, the `^` and `$` ARE part of the pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no shortcut, and adding `^` and `$` is not a hack. What you're doing is exactly what you're supposed to do in order to match an entire line.

Answer (score 0):

If it makes you feel better:

```
var match = Regex.Match(myInput, String.Format( "^{0}$", myPattern ) );
```

Or you may even be able to do this:

```
myPattern = "^" + myPattern + "$";
var match = Regex.Match(myInput, myPattern );
```

But as mentioned, it's just semantics. As long as your code is clear, it shouldn't be a problem when it comes to readability.